# How can I transform SolrQuery(SOLRJ) to URL?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

While using SOLRJ I would like to know how can I convert SolrQuery object to its URL representation with SOLR query syntax.  I tried to use .toString() method but it doesnt return proper query representation. Is there some other way how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend [ClientUtils.toQueryString](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html#toQueryString%28org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams,%20boolean%29) for this matter.

```
@Test
public void solrQueryToURL() {
  SolrQuery tmpQuery = new SolrQuery("some query");
  Assert.assertEquals("?q=some+query", ClientUtils.toQueryString(tmpQuery, false));
}
```

Within the source code of [HttpSolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer) you can see that this is used by the Solrj code itself for this reason.

```
public NamedList<Object> request(final SolrRequest request, final ResponseParser processor) throws SolrServerException, IOException {

  // ... other code left out

  if( SolrRequest.METHOD.GET == request.getMethod() ) {
    if( streams != null ) {
      throw new SolrException( SolrException.ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST, "GET can't send streams!" );
    }
    method = new HttpGet( baseUrl + path + ClientUtils.toQueryString( params, false ) );

  // ... other code left out

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

SolrJ (tested version 6.6.0 ) it is:

```
@Test
public void solrQueryToURL() {
  SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("query");
  Assert.assertEquals("?q=query", query.toQueryString());
}
```