# Error in parsing Solr response

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, solr4

I am using Solr-5.0.0.

I am tying to query Solr using Java. I am using group by clause here.

Its my code

```java
SolrQuery qry = new SolrQuery();

qry.setQuery("product_name:(laptops)");
qry.addFilterQuery("brand:dell OR brand: sony OR brand:samsung");
qry.setParam("group", true);
qry.setParam("group.field", "brand");
qry.setParam("stats", true);
qry.setParam("stats.field", "product_price");
qry.setFields("brand");
System.out.println(qry.toString());  

QueryRequest qryReq = new QueryRequest(qry);
QueryResponse resp = qryReq.process(solr);
System.out.println(resp.getResponse().toString());

// Here I am getting required response;
SolrDocumentList docs = resp.getResults();

//Below code giving me exception null pointer
for(int i = 0; i < docs.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println(docs.get(i)); 
}
```

But I am not able to parse the result of the query.I just need to get the brands and its corresponding count from the query in list or array

Comment: Could you paste the stacktrace to see where the NPE is coming from. Also check solr logs to see how many records are returned by solr for this search request.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the SolrQuery class you used.

I used solr in my program by creating a URL(Solr request) and getting the response as JSon as below.

Define the request as url

```
String url = "http://"+solr_server+":"+solr_port+"/solr/collection_name/select?q="+brand+"&wt=json&indent=true";
```

Read the solr result as JSon from request url

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(url);
```

Get the reponse and then docs - then iterate through the docs

```
JSONObject j1 = (JSONObject) json.get("response");
JSONArray j2 = j1.getJSONArray("docs");
for(int i=0;i<j2.length();i++){
    //do whatever you want to do
}
```

Remember to have the jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java-json/java-json.jar.zip in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Debug the query using [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341702/how-can-i-transform-solrquerysolrj-to-url) and see if the query is built properly. Then you can adopt to java