# Get request url from solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am using to solrj to query an index and at times kick off a reindex.

We are having some server issues, so I want to verify the url solrj is constructing. This is what I have tried:

```
public void indexSolr() throws SolrServerException, IOException {
    HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(solrIndexPath);
    logger.info("Indexing cp solr at " + solrIndexPath);

    // reindex to pickup new articles
    ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    params.set("qt", "/" + solrDataImportPath);
    params.set("command", "full-import");
    params.set("clean", "true");
    params.set("commit", "true");
    QueryResponse response = solr.query(params);
    logger.info("index url: " + response.getRequestUrl());
}
```

The problem is in that last line. `getRequestUrl()` is always null. I know solrj is indeed calling solr, because it does in fact kick off an index request (most of the time).

**How can I intercept or retrieve the url solrj is constructing for my request?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [How can I transform SolrQuery(SOLRJ) to URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341702/how-can-i-transform-solrquerysolrj-to-url) you can use [ClientUtils.toQueryString](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html#toQueryString%28org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams,%20boolean%29) for this matter.

In the javadoc you can see that this helper methods accepts `SolrParams` as input, which is what you have. To get the full URL you will need to concatenate this with the `solrIndexPath` you have in your code sample.

```
System.out.println(solrIndexPath + ClientUtils.toQueryString(params, false));
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Strange that this has to be constructed in this manner - but that's the trick. Thanks!